# Listinstances Changes Guid ID

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have my Listinstance in Sisual Studio every time i Deploy the Guid Id changes to a new value

```
http://servername:22222/sites/test/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=ExportList&List=213123-1234124-124124--12412142124
```

We says its first time, next time i deploy it has other values in the ID , how should i solve this because i use an Spsitedataquery were i want to query my lists , there i specifie my listid but the id always changes how should i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying listID in Spsitedataquery specify List TemplateID

```
SPSiteDataQuery dataQuery = new SPSiteDataQuery();
                dataQuery.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\">";
                dataQuery.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"10000\" />";
                dataQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />";
                string where ="<Where><Eq>";
                where += "<FieldRef Name=\"EmployeeID\"/>";
                where += "<Value Type='Integer'>" + txtEmpId.Text + "</Value>";
                where += "</Eq></Where>";

                dataQuery.Query = where;
                DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(dataQuery);
```

Disadvantage:In this case you will be querying all the lists with ServerTemplate=10000.